# CTL BADFILE SQLLDR

Tags: sql-loader

I need help. My objective is to create a CTL file. whenever sqlldr runs with this CTL it should not create a new bad file instead it should append the previous created BAD File. So that I have all the records present in a single file.

Can this be achieved, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write your own wrapper program or script around calling sqlldr.  After sqlldr runs, it would then have to check for the existence of the bad file and append it to a differently-named one as you mention above.

I question the value of this though.  Typically, if a .bad file was created, one would then investigate why, then either fix the table as a column could be sized wrong, fix the control file or even the data, then rerun the process, resulting in a new .bad (or not) based on the changes.

So, the next .bad file, if created, could contain the same records or new ones depending on what changed and are not really related to the previous .bad records. I'm afraid I don't see the value of keeping .bad records from previous runs together as they are meaningless without knowing the other circumstances under which they were created.

Perhaps if you added some more info as to why you want to do this we could suggest a different solution.